# With javascript: What is the best way to block scripting without block html markups (<b>, <p>, etc.)?

Tags: javascript, escaping, xss

I want to safely display a text coming from the user (by blocking scripts tags), but I need to accept html markups (b, p, li, ul, etc.).

It's need to be bullet proof against cross-site scripting attack.

Thank you!

Comment: as others have pointed out, the sanitizing can't be made client-side, it should be done server-side. You will be disappointed here since you can't possibly receive a different answer than "this can't be done with JS" :(

Comment: So you are saying that backbone.JS escape method isn't safe ?

Comment: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-escape

Comment: I only want to prevent executing javascript from an unsafe string. I don't care if a user can modify the DOM and remove the verification, cause the string is only displayed, not modified.

Comment: @ajax333221, Sanitizing done client-side can be a perfectly safe way to protect inputs before **using them client-side**, for example assigning to `innerHTML` as part of a rich text editor preview pane.  The thing you don't want to do is have the server trust those inputs because verifying that the client actually did sanitization is harder than just redoing the sanitization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a simple tag whitelist and you don't need to worry about attacks at or below the encoding level (as is the case from within browser-side JavaScript), you can do the following:

```
function sanitize(tagWhitelist, html) {
  // Get rid of all uses of '['.
  html = String(html).replace(/\[/g, '&#91;');

  // Consider all uses of '<' and replace whitelisted tags with markers like
  // [1] which are indices into a list of approved tag names.
  // Replace all other uses of < and > with entities.
  var tags = [];
  html = html.replace(
    /<!--[\s\S]*?-->|<(\/?)([a-z]\w*)(?:[^"'>]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>/g,
    function (_, close, tagName) {
      if (tagName) {
        tagName = tagName.toLowerCase();
        if (tagWhitelist.hasOwnProperty(tagName) && tagWhitelist[tagName]) {
          var index = tags.length;
          tags.push('<' + (close || '') + tagName + '>');
          return '[' + index + ']';
        }
      }
      return '';
    });

  // Escape HTML special characters.  Leave entities alone.
  html = html.replace(/[<>"'@\`\u0000]/g,
    function (c) {
      switch (c) {
        case '<': return '&lt;';
        case '>': return '&gt;';
        case '"': return '&quot;';
        case '\'': return '&#39;';
        case '@': return '&#64;';
      }
      return '&#' + c.charCodeAt(0) + ';';
    });
  if (html.indexOf('<') >= 0) { throw new Error(); }  // Sanity check.

  // Throw out any close tags that don't correspond to start tags.
  // If <table> is used for formatting, embedded HTML shouldn't be able
  // to use a mismatched </table> to break page layout.
  var open = [];
  for (var i = 0, n = tags.length; i < n; ++i) {
    var tag = tags[i];
    if (tag.charAt(1) === '/') {
      var idx = open.lastIndexOf(tag);
      if (idx < 0) { tags[i] = ""; }  // Drop close tag.
      else {
        tags[i] = open.slice(idx).reverse().join('');
        open.length = idx;
      }
    } else if (!HTML5_VOID_ELEMENTS.test(tag)) {
      open.push('</' + tag.substring(1));
    }
  }
  // Now html contains no tags or less-than characters that could become
  // part of a tag via a replacement operation and tags only contains
  // approved tags.
  // Reinsert the white-listed tags.
  html = html.replace(
       /\[(\d+)\]/g, function (_, index) { return tags[index]; });

  // Close any still open tags.
  // This prevents unclosed formatting elements like <ol> and <table> from
  // breaking the layout of containing HTML.
  return html + open.reverse().join('');
}

var HTML5_VOID_ELEMENTS = new RegExp(
     '^<(?:area|base|br|col|command|embed|hr|img|input'
     + '|keygen|link|meta|param|source|track|wbr)\\b');
```

which can be used like

```
sanitize({ p: true, b: true, i: true, br: true },
         "Hello, <b>World</b>!<script>alert(1337)<\/script>");
```

If you need more configurability, like the ability to allow attributes on tags, see the [Caja HTML sanitizer](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/JsHtmlSanitizer).

As others have pointed out, your server should not trust the result coming from the client so you should re-sanitize on the server before embedding the result into server-generated markup.

Comment: Mind if I ask why you're disallowing `"@"` and `"\"`?

Comment: @adlwalrus, `'@'` seems to show up in conditional code schemes.  IE uses it for conditional execution in its JavaScript engine, but while I'm pretty sure IE doesn't use it for conditional comments in HTML, I have low confidence that there aren't poorly documented browser features that use `'@'` to indicate that code follows.  `'"'` is a special character in HTML attributes.  I don't want to put out an HTML escaping method that isn't attribute safe, because once you advertise a function as converting HTML to plain text, people assume that it can be widely used.

Comment: Yes, but so are `!`, `=`, and `'`. Those are all, as you say, "HTML control characters." Why not escape those? Here's my attempt at a markdowney sort of formatting language. Do you have any feedback for my code? I'd appreciate actual comments instead of just editing the jsbin, cus that gets really confusing really quickly. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, `'` in fact serves an identical role within HTML as `"`'s.  Also, guessI just forgot the link.  Here it is: http://jsbin.com/uxofow/1/edit

Comment: @adlwalrus, Are we talking about the same code?  I don't say anything about "HTML control characters" at all and single quote is escaped.  Escaping the equals sign might be a good idea, but semicolon seems of marginal value and a line has to be drawn somewhere.

Comment: @adlwalrus, I'd rather not discuss large blocks of code in the comments to an answer that doesn't deal with that code.  If you put it up on codereview.stackexchange.com then I and others could give comments.  If you're concerned about confusion due to editing, then maybe you should put it up on github so that you have a revision history, and people can push you patches in an organized fashion.

Comment: Sorry, you don't talk about "special characters," not "control characters".  I suppose upon closer inspection that the regex does catch them, it just makes it into a reference and not an entity, as a catchall for when there's no specified entity in the switch.  I'll post my stuff on github and  link you here.  It'd be awesome if you could give it a look over.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using javascript for user input it won't be bulletproof no matter what you do.

Assuming you're writing a server-side backend, you should use the tried and true bbcode, there must be a library for it.

Comment: What do you mean by your first statement? Why is that never safe. Are you talking about input validation/sanitization of data sent to the server only performed client side? If so, I agree

Comment: Any client-side code can be changed by the client - he would have to validate it all over again when it reaches the server anyway.

Comment: Yep. But javascript input validation could still make sense, if data was immediately preview on the client before being sent to the server. Having it on the serer is mandatory though.